# Best Way to certify DO-178 Communications Stack?

Tags: commercial-aviation, arinc-429

We currently have a piece of hardware running an RTOS that needs the communication stack to be certified to DAL-B. Everything has already been developed for non commercial aerospace applications, although we now have a commercial aerospace customer who is interested in our solution.

The communications stack handles a variety of different communication methods, and we're deciding on a make vs buy decision. These communication methods include ARINC 429, RS422 and Ethernet.

Are there any products out there that are DO-178 certified and handle these communication protocols? Or will we need to go through the certification process for our own implementations?

Comment: I'm not sure "best way" is answerable, but given the body of your question, it seems just a matter of differently phrasing the title.

Comment: Which RTOS? Is it certified already?

Comment: A. I don't know of any that can be purchased. Everywhere I worked, we developed our own. B. Even if you find one, you still have to integrate into your product and certify your product. Having a purchased stack would provide some certification documentation but it would not be complete for your application. C. I suggest hiring a Consultant DER. You can find one in the [FAA Consultant DER Directory](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/designees_delegations/designee_types/media/DERDirectory.pdf). Hiring an expert will save you time and money.

Comment: As @Gerry stated, it sounds like at least talking with a Consultant DER is the place to start, as showing compliance to DO-178C is no small task.

Comment: @selectstriker2 Real Time Operating System.

Comment: @JuanJimenez, yes, but which one?

Comment: @selectstriker2 You changed your comment, and if you now want to know which RTOS is being used you should ask the poster, not me...

Comment: @JuanJimenez, my original comment was never edited, and I was asking the OP which one. I should have looked better at your response, as I thought it was coming from the OP